# What s the best archetype to create a test only project

Tags: java, maven, automation

I am about to start my test only project using maven.
in this Java project i will only  write classes in  test packages, and will use some property, sql, xml resource files.

I tried crating projects using bot maven-archetype-quickstart and maven-archetype-simple but neither of them looks like the one I wanted.

Any ideas ?

Comment: quickstart is fine... it doesn't 'create' tests for you though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need a project with a structure to accommodate y resources files as well....

Comment: If you want a resources directory you can use [maven-archetype-webapp](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html) and it will build a resource directory too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple *Java* project archetype, with main and test folders along with the source and resources folder, you can use the *net.avh4.mvn.archetype:java-1.6-archetype* which will provide an eclipse/git ready java simple project with below structure:

```
project-root
|_ src
|  |_ main
|  |  |_ java
|  |  |_ resources
|  |_ test
|     |_ java
|     |_ resources
|_ .classpath
|_ .project
```

Note that this archetype is a community delivered one and not maintained by an IT vendor but by a github user [avh4](https://github.com/avh4) who provides already an alternative to the archetype above by simply runnig below command in a `bash` terminal:

```
bash <(curl http://archetypes.github.io/bootstrap.sh)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.avh4.mvn.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=java-1.6-archetype` generated the project. Looks pretty much the  way I wanted. Sorry I still cant plus, your reply as I don't have enough reputation at the moment.

Comment: Glad you found what you are looking for. PS: You still can accept the answer even though you can not upvote it and I will manage to make sure you have the necessary reputation ;)